Why am I getting an unexpected symbol error ONLY in RStudio?
I am in the process of writing some code in RStudio to fetch a page from ProQuest, and noticed that I kept having an Error: unexpected symbol in error popping up. At first, I thought that I may have a malformed string, but I removed more and more code, verified that the line in question looks okay, and I'm still seeing the error.
Here's the code:
a = 'lit_osano=v1; __gsas=ID=6783126c6ff2ac26:T=1708355272:RT=1708355272:S=ALNI_MZTTxHeDn1O7RLcPmFZiG9bcBOfZw; fpestid=pA_QTIchdJg7C_Sg4deJRaDhkU5Oj6pInbAj2CFVUjDOmnnt24zuahzfMzdtA1Yg8toNtQ; _ga_HBSP4LWR7W=GS1.2.1708383133.1.0.1708383133.0.0.0; _ga_ZSCY2GBGHL=GS1.1.1708553829.1.1.1708553901.57.0.0; _fbp=fb.1.1708610487657.86696502; _ga_VS1L32MSMD=GS1.2.1708614083.1.1.1708614259.0.0.0; _hjSessionUser_1459581=eyJpZCI6IjBlNTVkNTRmLWFkZDUtNTc5NC05ZmI1LTg4YTBkYTllZTVhYSIsImNyZWF0ZWQiOjE3MDg3MTgzNzIyNTQsImV4aXN0aW5nIjp0cnVlfQ==; _ga_14KG9BFZ3B=GS1.1.1708966974.2.0.1708966974.60.0.0; _ga_NZN56SGS69=GS1.1.1709228279.1.0.1709228298.0.0.0; amplitude_id_584b102d29f40e238512b2fda5b1ccc3columbia.edu=eyJkZXZpY2VJZCI6Ijg4OGNmNzBkLWUzMzUtNGNkNC1hOTFhLTRjYzUwNjhmMzg0ZSIsInVzZXJJZCI6bnVsbCwib3B0T3V0IjpmYWxzZSwic2Vzc2lvbklkIjoxNzA5NjcyNDI4NDkzLCJsYXN0RXZlbnRUaW1lIjoxNzA5NjcyNTc0OTQ1LCJldmVudElkIjo0LCJpZGVudGlmeUlkIjo0LCJzZXF1ZW5jZU51bWJlciI6OH0=; AMCV_1B6E34B85282A0AC0A490D44%40AdobeOrg=MCMID|58492033748044004970686706844290882026; rskxRunCookie=0; rCookie=e5tw8fwu33krnnxcbs94aqltf62j95; _ga_6P3K823TXK=GS1.1.1709691334.2.0.1709691334.0.0.0; _ga_H409811TE1=GS1.1.1709747535.1.0.1709747542.0.0.0; _ga_P88NW4KD8K=GS1.1.1711465060.1.1.1711465133.0.0.0; _hjSessionUser_1518123=eyJpZCI6ImQ2MzA1ZDUzLTVhYzktNTYxYi1hMjVlLWY0MzA5Y2UyODNhMCIsImNyZWF0ZWQiOjE3MTEwNDAyODY0MjcsImV4aXN0aW5nIjp0cnVlfQ==; _ga_QLVYV2NS59=GS1.1.1711564866.2.0.1711564867.0.0.0; amp_d4783f=0tYC6VdiWTfph8K0tqxpxH...1hq0m40jl.1hq0m40jm.1.0.1; amplitude_id_9f6c0bb8b82021496164c672a7dc98d6_edmcolumbia.edu=eyJkZXZpY2VJZCI6IjU0MTdhYWRmLWQzMGQtNDBhOC1hZDY3LWQ4N2NjNjJlYTI3OVIiLCJ1c2VySWQiOm51bGwsIm9wdE91dCI6ZmFsc2UsInNlc3Npb25JZCI6MTcxMTU2NzY3MTk2OCwibGFzdEV2ZW50VGltZSI6MTcxMTU2NzY3MTk2OSwiZXZlbnRJZCI6MCwiaWRlbnRpZnlJZCI6NSwic2VxdWVuY2VOdW1iZXIiOjV9; amplitude_id_408774472b1245a7df5814f20e7484d0columbia.edu=eyJkZXZpY2VJZCI6ImRhYWIwNDIwLTExMTQtNGVmOC1hYjMxLWVlOWY1ZjM5ZjVmYiIsInVzZXJJZCI6Ii0yMDI5MjM3OTMiLCJvcHRPdXQiOmZhbHNlLCJzZXNzaW9uSWQiOjE3MTE1Njc2NzIxOTYsImxhc3RFdmVudFRpbWUiOjE3MTE1Njc2NzI0MDUsImV2ZW50SWQiOjUsImlkZW50aWZ5SWQiOjE3LCJzZXF1ZW5jZU51bWJlciI6MjJ9; _ga_LBKMVBR2K0=GS1.1.1711657464.3.0.1711657480.0.0.0; _ga_LM9KZ2WWND=GS1.1.1711745078.2.0.1711745078.0.0.0; _ga_6R1H3RV989=GS1.1.1712581262.5.1.1712582719.0.0.0; _hjSessionUser_1283988=eyJpZCI6IjUxYjQwMGNjLTI0OGUtNWRhNy1iZjJmLTkwNDcwMDAzZWYyNSIsImNyZWF0ZWQiOjE3MTI2MDI0NzkwMzMsImV4aXN0aW5nIjp0cnVlfQ==; _hjSessionUser_1108297=eyJpZCI6ImJiNTdkZGVkLTk0ZWUtNTVmYi05N2RiLWUzZjRiNWU4YmNhZSIsImNyZWF0ZWQiOjE3MTI4NDU2Njk4ODIsImV4aXN0aW5nIjp0cnVlfQ==; _ga_961MJHBFLW=GS1.1.1712938442.2.0.1712938442.0.0.0; _ga_WDV1H8SFX8=GS1.1.1712938806.3.1.1712938867.0.0.0; _ga_2SWDCZ62XH=GS1.2.1713195465.1.0.1713195465.0.0.0; _ga_34P23DDWLD=GS1.1.1713197772.2.0.1713197772.0.0.0; acceptcookies=true; _hjSessionUser_1941698=eyJpZCI6IjdkNzA1ODY5LWUzZDQtNWEwZS1hYzc1LTk5Mjk2MmVjODQzMCIsImNyZWF0ZWQiOjE3MTMxOTc4NTM2OTUsImV4aXN0aW5nIjp0cnVlfQ==; kndctr_1B6E34B85282A0AC0A490D44_AdobeOrg_identity=CiY1ODQ5MjAzMzc0ODA0NDAwNDk3MDY4NjcwNjg0NDI5MDg4MjAyNlIQCKTerIzhMRgBKgNWQTYwAfAB2LH4v-8x; _uetvid=6101ae70db5f11ee9be2912970d79df9; lastRskxRun=1713557611389; _ga_S74SMTYBRV=GS1.1.1713712054.2.0.1713712056.0.0.0; _ga_84DKSE6XLT=GS1.1.1713738580.14.0.1713738580.0.0.0; _ga_9C4T5P6PP6=GS1.1.1713969996.13.0.1713969996.60.0.0; _ga_890CVKT79K=GS1.1.1714076268.4.0.1714076268.0.0.0; __gads=ID=826e802babc32426:T=1708718588:RT=1714076950:S=ALNI_MbPCLkvFlHyHJDCDZdTgFbKM5tEYw; __eoi=ID=bca0a02f413136fe:T=1708718588:RT=1714076950:S=AA-AfjYOW4w55NhuGRjE1Hmkj4Zc; _ga_0HYE8YG0M6=GS1.1.1714154816.9.1.1714154819.0.0.0; _ga_9E7VT47G3J=GS1.1.1715109284.2.1.1715109299.0.0.0; _ga_FWY5Q9GFZ5=GS1.1.1715109313.6.1.1715111633.0.0.0; _ga_H2KGDH2XNS=GS1.1.1715543838.6.0.1715543838.0.0.0; _ga_CBV5E5LWRW=GS1.1.1715543839.14.1.1715543841.58.0.0; _ga_G7V965V32T=GS1.1.1717689449.4.0.1717689449.0.0.0; _ga_W1QZFY2E7L=GS1.1.1718303487.2.1.1718303898.0.0.0; _gcl_au=1.1.356906094.1718897215; _clck=fb4w2j%7C2%7Cfmw%7C0%7C1513; _ga_640JZ5FVQE=GS1.2.1720565676.1.1.1720565713.0.0.0; _ga_V1FJWPWNMQ=GS1.1.1720570592.6.1.1720570678.0.0.0; _ga_PNZW5NCBLB=GS1.1.1720711561.4.1.1720711587.0.0.0; _hp2_props.3001039959=%7B%22Base.appName%22%3A%22Canvas%22%7D; _hp2_id.3001039959=%7B%22userId%22%3A%227720952915041999%22%2C%22pageviewId%22%3A%228122882584159243%22%2C%22sessionId%22%3A%22742440882900078%22%2C%22identity%22%3A%22uu-2-e51af2b1aa3caa69213d33abfae822f0d2d737b09d7468ca97c32d134c8f0e7d-ntZgkM1nh5DIuczSIKJlraBGE1FVxCiZ4KsH5puX%22%2C%22trackerVersion%22%3A%224.0%22%2C%22identityField%22%3Anull%2C%22isIdentified%22%3A1%7D; _ga_H0JFCZH43J=GS1.1.1721680766.2.1.1721680796.0.0.0; _ga_QH0CR0CYJ5=GS1.1.1721687474.2.0.1721687474.60.0.0; _ga_1SREPM2ZFM=GS1.1.1721687478.251.0.1721687478.0.0.0; _ga_VYTTCRZQS7=GS1.1.1722103752.9.1.1722105465.0.0.0; _gid=GA1.2.1697126253.1722264053; authSub=1; SE=1800; fulltextShowAll=YES; AMCV_4D6368F454EC41940A4C98A6%40AdobeOrg=-2121179033%7CMCIDTS%7C19934%7CMCMID%7C66438832774704653990331287138924109292%7CMCAAMLH-1722875177%7C7%7CMCAAMB-1722875177%7CRKhpRz8krg2tLO6pguXWp5olkAcUniQYPHaMWWgdJ3xzPWQmdj0y%7CMCOPTOUT-1722277577s%7CNONE%7CMCAID%7CNONE%7CvVersion%7C5.3.0%7CMCCIDH%7C-12133580; mbox=PC#b9a5f48be05f438f9f6ea0f9ce642145.34_0#1785515211|session#133060116b6447909eac581fcbf00480#1722272271; OptanonAlertBoxClosed=2024-07-29T16:27:39.894Z; _ga_795XZ9TLZF=GS1.1.1722270821.7.1.1722270822.0.0.0; s_pers=%20v8%3D1722276386172%7C1816884386172%3B%20v8_s%3DLess%2520than%25201%2520day%7C1722278186172%3B; _ga_RD6KG3D5M9=GS1.1.1722345018.1.1.1722345030.0.0.0; cf_clearance=Zfotuv.htkTy2yVI4u1hOL6hsGpiTq_mwQBYgqcZ6Kw-1722357562-1.0.1.1-CJypSoNHEdpFmMy4kVUKyYB7bcuA4gCX5GZekEgMpqpDF1VkYgdrwlRU4AhV51HohONMqN5iBMjUfZHTHgInqA; oneSearchTZ=-240; __utma=228172571.956888503.1708304470.1722372901.1722372901.1; __utmc=228172571; __utmz=228172571.1722372901.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); AppVersion=r2024.7.0.3085; _ga_R857CTTQWZ=GS1.2.1722435845.52.1.1722437574.0.0.0; ezproxy=lIYAqApUK1DGQ6v; ezproxyl=lIYAqApUK1DGQ6v; ezproxyn=lIYAqApUK1DGQ6v; JSESSIONID=86CED75D9A7FCECCE325384CD1FA0727.i-0d76e647e95d867bb; authenticatedBy=TOKEN; authThrough=xlL6UsJwAMlb8PFSWgdjsbtSPuadclNwiRpa4RbX21W2RaoIOez3iFV4Ldf+E9iLU3NyQHEgE7X/0zJOEVtrtV7UH1Q7iIG+Z7sLkptiUw6SFRlCo5pF0eww8/NEgzPZ; AWSELB=276741051C90E6B1B306DF6C7ADF26F332A94E5A307CF86061AD9A2F0AB5AEDBAFF3199CAB172C7E8141DAF5175F9EB4AE55D51DF2B1A0FC5C736D0852EC8272F08C44E83722B339419844573B66BE0DA9D0C0F059; _ga=GA1.1.956888503.1708304470; __cf_bm=34vPqRzTGBbv54RG5Wpw9iO8ZQo1OJUMkinyCHQwgRE-1722480235-1.0.1.1-5j_GIsrARLspIilJj.n9w8AI4QnDErqdTZZyTb56JY7Z1_LzMZ2W66nTcI.lL.vS0i0FiG96nLi2NfOt5lLVbA; _ga_XBLC1VPMZ5=GS1.1.1722480852.7.0.1722480852.0.0.0; OptanonConsent=isGpcEnabled=0&datestamp=Wed+Jul+31+2024+22%3A54%3A13+GMT-0400+(Eastern+Daylight+Time)&version=202403.1.0&browserGpcFlag=0&isIABGlobal=false&hosts=&consentId=095f66fc-0db3-4f18-be90-7d4c234a0515&interactionCount=1&isAnonUser=1&landingPath=NotLandingPage&groups=C0001%3A1%2CC0003%3A1%2CC0004%3A1%2CC0005%3A1%2CC0002%3A1&AwaitingReconsent=false&geolocation=US%3BNY; osTimestamp=1722480853.543; _ga_F7FWH0G9HJ=GS1.1.20240801015208154:417546.17.1.1722480853.0.0.0; availability-zone=us-east-1f; ST=1722480853; ST=1722481031; availability-zone=us-east-1f'
headers = c(
  'Cookie' = a,
  'Referer' = 'https://www-proquest-com.ezproxy.cul.columbia.edu/news/results/BD2FC43409DA4C5CPQ/1?accountid=10226'
)

My best hunch is that there is some limit (maybe a RAM limit?) specific to my local environment (R Studio running on new MacBook Air). Have you ever seen an issue like this before? What happens if you try to run this same code snippet on your computer?
Some additional weirdness that makes this error more confounding:

I can get this code to work in other environments. I went to https://www.mycompiler.io/new/r, pasted in the exact same code, and it succeeded.
The issue appears to be related to the length of the string a: I've tried arbitrarily removing characters from a, and bringing it below a certain length allows the program to succeed.


related? https://forum.posit.co/t/does-console-impose-an-upper-limit-on-the-length-of-strings/12872/11

What happens if you put the code in a file and source it: source("myfile.R") ?

Yes, there's a limit on individual line lengths when running in interactive mode in R. Rather than putting the literal value in the script itself, you might try reading large input from a file as data. That way it doesn't have to go though the language parser so it won't encounter the input string length limit.

Thank you so much! Turning off interactive mode worked perfectly.
